# Angular 2 with NgRx

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

My question is to those who use NgRx. In the official documentation, action, reducer, etc. they no longer write class base. But many articles and video tutorials use classes. I would like to know which is better to use?

Documentation link :
New version without class:  https://ngrx.io/guide/store/actions
Version 7 with class: https://v7.ngrx.io/guide/store/actions

Answer (score 1):

Better is to follow the latest version - to use helper functions instead of classes.
Staring from ngrx6 codebase is moving slowly to helper functions.

Actually classes were used for actions only (a reducer is a function, an effect is a rxjs data stream), but with the `type` property it was redundant because any object with a type property can be a recognizable action, therefore it's enough to create an object instead of class, extra benifit here is that it can be serialised and passed through different data stream (not only frontend app). To keep its interface type safe and facilitate its definition the  `createAction` function was introduced.